# How to mount a bucket in a Google Run application?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

My final goal is to mount a bucket inside a container to be deployed with google run.

In order to mount a bucket, I am using gcsfuse that requires a privileged container. 
(https://github.com/maciekrb/gcs-fuse-sample et.al...)

With a VirtualMachine I would use:

```
gcloud compute instances create-with-container \
    [...] \
    --container-privileged
```

While with google run:

```
gcloud beta run deploy [...]
```

But it doesn't seem to have this option.

Any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

> My final goal is to mount a bucket inside a container to be deployed
>   with google run.

What you are trying to do is not supported by Cloud Run.

Cloud Run has a few rules (and a few more):

1. The container runs beginning with the first HTTP request to it.
2. The container is eligible to be terminated after the last HTTP Request returns.
3. Cloud Run containers are stateless.
4. Cloud Run does not support background processes.

To use gcs-fuse in Cloud Run would require creating TCP connection that run independently of the state of the container. When Cloud Run puts the container to sleep your connections will fail.

Comment: Thanks for helping. So the only way to use a pre existing dataset on a file system (not db) is to mount a persistent disk like this: https://cloud.google.com/filestore/docs/accessing-fileshares or with Google cloud filestore like this: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/gcp-filestore-csi-driver. I am wrong?

Comment: That is not supported either in Cloud Run.

Comment: So no way to use data that are not stored in a database?

Comment: Totally right, I would to mount the bucket in order to write the output in the same place. Now the silly question is: can I just write the file and then push it on the bucket (simply doing gsutils cp filename gs://bucket-name)?

Comment: You cannot use `gsutils` without a lot of work. This would require a container with a lot of extra stuff (bloated). Instead, use the Cloud SDK and write code to interface with Cloud Storage which is easy. Remember, you don't have a CLI in a Cloud Run container. Most Cloud Run containers do not include shells such as bash. Don't approach Cloud Run as an operating system.

Comment: It is not much work to use gsutils and you can use whatever containers you build. So what 'most' containers do is out of scope. You can use whatever shells and tools you have added to your container.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of imprecise definitions in answers and comments of 'supported'. Getting support, maybe not. works? yes. Tutorials provided by google? yes. gsfuse is one way. It is Pre-GA: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse

Also I use gsutils installed in a container with no ill side-effects, contrary to some comments. When someone asks 'any way to...?' and the response is 'not supported' that implies it is not a viable way, when it actually works. The lifecycle of run instances are the biggest issue. But mounted gsfuse mounts should be done in entrypoint scripts to survive and remain avail.

Answer (score 0):

That is something you cannot do with Google Run product. Instead, you need to use Google App Engine Flex, which does not have timeout like Google App Engine or Google Cloud Functions. And also you should use Google Storage blob access functions to access files.

Answer (score 0):

I can highly recommend the [gcsfuse project](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/releases)
Remember that you either need to allow your vm to access proper googleAPIS or you should provide a json key with proper permissions

Mounting of the bucket directly to your VM just like nfs mount. It has quite decent performance too and very simple usage. [Docu here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcsfuse/blob/master/docs/mounting.md#credentials)

To mount it manually run the following

```
gcsfuse my-bucket /path/to/mount
```

To mount it automatically after each reboot add this to your `/etc/fstab` file.(uid and gid are optional)

```
my-bucket /mount/point gcsfuse rw,x-systemd.requires=network-online.target,uid=1001,gid=1001
```